# Infragistics Excel worksheet read value instead of reference

Tags: excel, reference, infragistics

I have an Excel file (xlsx) where two colums have referenced values. Actually in the cells you see values, but when you select a cell, in the formula field you see a reference address. All the values exist even if there are no files with content, because they are referenced. But Infragistics Excel Worksheet selects references and because it cannot find files it shows !REF#.
How can I force it to ignore references and read values?

Comment: what about copy/paste your sheet data in another place with "paste values" action ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug which has been fixed. It should work in the latest Service Releases of 11.1 and later. If it does not, in which file format are your files saved and which version are you using?

Comment: I am using Infragistics 10.3 version. My data is in xlsx file.

Comment: In that case, you will need to upgrade to a later version. 10.3 is no longer supported.